# How to asynchronously load a controller, and attach it to the angular module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a controller I want to asynchronously fetch, which require the angular-cookies library.

Therefore I am using jQuery to fetch and run the angular-cookies library, then fetch and execute the file with the controller. My current code is as below:

```
$.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-cookies.min.js", function() {
  app.requires.push('ngCookies');
  $.getScript( "js/mailListCtrl.php", function() {
    console.log("Succesfully fetched controller mailListCtrl");
  });
});
```

This work fine, and both the scripts are run in global scope, however, the controller mailListCtrl is never attached to my module. This is how mailListCtrl.js looks like:

```
console.log("mailListCtrl.js is loaded"); // This is executed

app.controller('mailListCtrl', ['$http', '$timeout', '$cookies', '$scope', function ($http, $timeout, $cookies, $scope) {

  console.log("mailListCtrl is loaded, and code is executing"); // This is never executed

  // Lots of code...

}]);
```

So my problem is that I am not able to attach the controller to my angular module after the initial page load. I would be very grateful if anyone had a solution to this.

Comment: Is `app` a global variable? Are there more than one apps?

Comment: There is only one app, and yes it is a global variable. It is declared like this: `var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually really simple. Since this is a long time ago I do not remember where I got this from, but adding this code to `app.config` makes it possible to attach controllers after the initial bootstrapping of the angular module:

```
app.controller = function( name, constructor ) {
  $controllerProvider.register( name, constructor );
  return( this );
};
```

NB: remember to inject `$controllerProvider` as a dependency for `app.config`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to `Bootstrap` your app manually.

```
$.getScript( "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-cookies.min.js", function() {
  app.requires.push('ngCookies');
  $.getScript( "js/mailListCtrl.php", function() {
    console.log("Succesfully fetched controller mailListCtrl");

    var myAppDiv = angular.element("#divThatIsApp"); //in quotes should be the ID of the element where you have ngApp declared
    angular.bootstrap(myAppDiv, ["app"]); // in quotes should be your app name
  });
});
```

and remove the `ng-app` from your  element. If you need to recompile a particular view then you will have to fiddle with the `injector`. Technically, you have to design your app right so you don't need to recompile.

Here is a [good article about bootstrapping angular apps](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, a few things still remain unclear to me. First of all, will this declare a new angular app? And second which element is the "element where you have ngApp declared"? Is it the `<html>`-tag where I declared the original app? And at last, the app name, would that be the name of the original app, or a new name?

Comment: It will bootstrap the app. It will preserve all the settings like controllers, directives. Will just reapply things to the DOM (one way to put it).

Comment: @tjespe If you declared your ngApp="app" in <html>, in that case you just pass `document` so angular.element(document) instead of #divThatIsApp

Comment: Ok, this gives me an error though: `App already bootstrapped with this element 'document'`
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd?p0=document

Comment: @tjespe Forgot to mention, remove the ngApp="app" from HTML since you are manually bootstrapping it

Comment: But I want to initially bootstrap the app when I first load the page as well, this won't happen if I remove the `ng-app="app"` right?

Comment: I forgot that starting 1.8 they stopped allowing multiple subsequent bootstrapping. You would need to fiddle with the `injector` to force a recompile. If this does not answer your question, I would prefer to delete this answer. Edited my answer.